# Making Code PHP 8 Compatible, With Backwards Compatibility To PHP 7

Tags: php, parameters, compatibility, required

Good Afternoon,

Currently trying to work out the best way to get the following code to be PHP 8 compatible, with backwards compatibility to at least PHP 7:

function wpsc_get_meta( $object_id = 0, $meta_key, $object_type ) {

```
global $wpdb;

$cache_object_id = $object_id = (int) $object_id;
$meta_key = wpsc_sanitize_meta_key( $meta_key );

$meta_tuple = compact( 'object_type', 'object_id', 'meta_key' );
$meta_tuple = apply_filters( 'wpsc_get_meta', $meta_tuple );

// Get cached meta
$meta_value = wp_cache_get( $cache_object_id, $meta_tuple['object_type'] );

// If not cached, get and cache all object meta
if ( $meta_value === false ) {
    $meta_values = wpsc_update_meta_cache( $meta_tuple['object_type'], $meta_tuple['object_id'] );
    $meta_value = $meta_values[ $meta_tuple['object_id'] ];
}

if ( isset( $meta_value[ $meta_tuple['meta_key'] ] ) ) {
    return maybe_unserialize( $meta_value[ $meta_tuple['meta_key'] ] );
}

return '';
```

}

The first line of code is what needs changing as below:

function wpsc_get_meta( $object_id = 0, $meta_key, $object_type ) {

have changed to:

function wpsc_get_meta( $object_id, $meta_key, $object_type ) {

and wanted to check if this is the best way, by removing the zero?

The actual error messages displayed are:

Deprecated: Required parameter $meta_key follows optional parameter $object_id

Deprecated: Required parameter $object_type follows optional parameter $object_id

Removing the zero as mentioned above seems to fix the error message, but not sure if this is the best way of resolving this?

Have also tried the following, which doesn't seem to work:

function wpsc_get_meta( $meta_key, $object_type, $object_id = 0 ) {

If anybody has any suggestions, it would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Deprecation notices don't **need** to be resolved. The code is still working, but maybe won't work in a **future** version. Also, it's documented since years that you should not use mandatory parameters after optional ones

Comment: The solution would be to reorder the arguments. Keep in mind that you need to do this on all calls of such a method. And "doesn't seem to work" is not a valid description of the problem you are facing after changing the parameter order

Comment: Hi Nico. Many thanks for your feedback. Sorry I should have mentioned the error message that we get when we reorder the arguments, which is: Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in this line of code: $meta_value = $meta_values[ $meta_tuple['object_id'] ];

Comment: I assume (or hope) you know that that plugin is no longer [being maintained](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-this-plugin-dead-64/) and that the developers have [moved on](https://wpecommerce.org/). I would recommend looking for an alternative solution instead of trying to patch this to work in a newer version of PHP. If you do patch this, please fork the main plugin and contribute back to the community!

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your comments. Yes, I'm fully aware that the plugin isn't being maintained anymore. Have been using the plugin for a number of years and really enjoy the plugin. Will certainly be forking and contributing back, as this is another reason for trying to patch things, so that other members of the community can benefit as well.

Comment: Although I agree with Nico in general, for BC reasons specific to this case, I would recommend either removing the default value as you did, but then also reset the default in the function itself if null, or, give sane defaults to the other parameters. You might have to walk those functions deeper to figure out what “sane defaults” mean, too.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I would also encourage you to throw your own depreciation notices for future users, if you detect invalid uses of your modified functions.

Comment: Adding the following seems to have resolved this:  if( is_array($meta_value) ) {
  $meta_value = $meta_values[ $meta_tuple['object_id'] ];
 }

Comment: Should have mentioned that the above code on my last comment relates to this: Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in this line of code: $meta_value = $meta_values[ $meta_tuple['object_id'] ];